# How to remove bad smell from kitchen?

Tags: smell, kitchen-safety

how to maintain a healthy, neat and clean kitchen in an apartment without smell as apartment is too small, there is no direct sunlight, no window only exhaust fan, rest of apartment have wide window and good air passage but kitchen is closed. I try to clean it daily but the bad smell remain there.

Answer (score 3):

Bad smells don't suddenly appear: they have a source. The way to get rid of it is removing the source. If there is a persistent bad smell, I would recommend going though the kitchen from top to bottom and clean everything. This will probably take several hours to most of a day, depending on how many people help and how big the kitchen is.

This includes cleaning in drawers (removing inserts and cleaning them as well) and cupboards, pulling out appliances like the stove and refrigerator (maybe a piece of some food fell behind the stove while cooking and is spreading a bad smell?) and potentially even having a plumber check that there's nothing wrong with the sink / waste disposal. You should also change or clean the filters in the exhaust fan. Hopefully after this the source of the smell will be discovered and removed.

Once the bad smell is gone, you can maintain the kitchen by cleaning daily as you have been doing and making sure you get fresh air into the room. Leave the door open and have a window open in some other room to help get fresh air into the kitchen.

Answer (score 2):

When you are confident you have removed the source of the smell, sometimes an irritating odor can linger in the air of a room with limited circulation.  The method for dealing with this, which has worked for me in the past, is to half fill a pan with boiling water and add my favorite spices.  Continue to boil the water in the pan for ten minutes and stir, so that the spices do not stick to the sides and burn.
This may be more of a cover up method, which you can use as a temporary measure until the cause is fixed.  At other times, I found that when the spice smell had faded, so had the original odor that I had rejected.